# Ambiguous Flutter error : Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Tags: android, gradle, flutter, android-gradle-plugin

I just add a library for downloading to Flutter dependencies (flutter_downloader: ^1.3.3) then I run and I receive this error, not even a single line of code I added!
How can I make this error more clear and find out what the compiler is trying to say!

```
 Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to your app gradle dependencies.

`implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:27.0.1-android'`

Answer (score 3):

please try **flutter_downloader: 1.2.1**

Comment: Just this : Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1